# Bluetooth won't work: "hci0 Reading Intel version information failed"

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez

I had bluetooth working fine till today when I needed to add a USB storage device. The usb device didn't work, the system couldn't see it (`lsblk` didn't show anything). So tried rebooting the system. Before that I did `pacman -Syu`. Also I installed (later uninstalled virtualbox-ext-oracle) from AUR. Now the usb storage drive is seen by the system but bluetooth does not work. Could you help?

```
[I] ➜ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service bluetooth.target 

[I] ➜ systemctl | grep bluetoo                            
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device               loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0                 
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                      loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                                  
  bluetooth.service                                                                                loaded active running   Bluetooth service                                                                      
  bluetooth.target                                                                                 loaded active active    Bluetooth                                                                              


[I] ➜ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# 

[I] ➜ sudo rmmod btusb    

[I] ➜ sudo modprobe btusb

[I] ➜ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   10.777582] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.777590] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.777592] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.777594] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.777595] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.329615] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.329615] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.329618] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.036936] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   13.037031] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[  779.744086] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[  779.744091] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[ 2330.676540] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[ 2330.676549] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout



[I] ➜ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

[I] ➜ pa -Qs blue
local/bluedevil 1:5.17.5-1 (plasma)
    Integrate the Bluetooth technology within KDE workspace and applications
local/bluez 5.52-2
    Daemons for the bluetooth protocol stack
local/bluez-libs 5.52-2
    Deprecated libraries for the bluetooth protocol stack
local/bluez-qt 5.66.0-1 (kf5)
    Qt wrapper for Bluez 5 DBus API
local/bluez-utils 5.52-2
    Development and debugging utilities for the bluetooth protocol stack
local/pulseaudio-bluetooth 13.0-3
    Bluetooth support for PulseAudio

[I] ➜ id
uid=1000(art) gid=1000(art) groups=1000(art),108(vboxusers),991(lp)

[I] ➜ uname -a
Linux artpc 5.4.12-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 14 Jan 2020 21:44:31 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update. Post at ArchLinux forum: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1883397#p1883397

Comment: From archlinux thread I noticed your issue went away later. I experienced exact same dmesg output with machine which has Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 after unexpected power loss. It did not recover after multiple soft reboots. Eventually I tried complete power off (including physical button on power supply) and it came back fine.

Comment: Same situation as Tadas. I had rebooted a few times, but after reading the comment I did as he said. Not enough, but I tried again even disconnecting the power supply and giving it half a minute, and turned it back on and everything worked again. Not gonna try to understand it, just happy it works again.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on the 5.15.41 kernel and AX200.
This resolved it for me:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo rmmod btintel

sudo modprobe btintel
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271459

Comment: I'm on Linux 6.1.11 and this still fix the problem at the reboots when I have this problem

Comment: Same here. I don't know how, but this is the only thing that fixes it.

Comment: 6.1.31 still has this problem _sometimes_. It looks like hardware issue, the hardware is not getting ready soon enough, or something.

Answer (score 0):

I am using USB Kali Linux (or) Live Kali Linux with kernel version 6.

Issue is `hciconfig` doesn't detect the bluetooth adapter , it shows me `bdaddress:00:00:00:00:00`. Command `hciconfig hci0 up`
shows `Operation not permitted(1)`

After I tried all the above sort of things lot of browsing spend much more time than expert I finally resolved it by the steps below:

- open terminal
- type command `sudo apt-get -y install inxi`, then `inxi -bE`

This shows complete hardware details in your device.
Here you can see Bluetooth address other than 00:00..., that is your system Bluetooth address.

- use command `hciconfig` - here the bdaddress now changes
- to start Bluetooth service again type commands

```
service bluetooth start
bluetoothctl
scan on
```

Here controller is registered with your Bluetooth hardware address.

Connect your Bluetooth device now.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sh -c "modprobe -r btusb; sleep 2; modprobe btusb"
```

[Source](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215167#c50)

One shouldn't need to do this, but it seems to do the magic.